# undefnied var in second function

Tags: actionscript-2

I have a class in as2 that I have simplified below. The first trace statement in singleLine() works fine (shows 3). But the second in repeat() shows undefined.

Anyone know why?

> class DrawLines{
>
> ```
> private var numPoints:Number;
>
> public function DrawLines(arr:Array){
>   numPoints = arr.length;
>   singleLine();
> }
>
> private function singleLine(){
>     setInterval(repeat,200);
>     trace(numPoints);
> }
>
> private function repeat(){
>     trace(numPoints);
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: I think you forgot to include your code.

Comment: Ok don't know what happened there but the code is added now

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it will help, but have you tried using this.numPoints instead of just numPoints in the moive?